# How to apply multiple filters on a Django template when i use django-ckeditor without error?

Tags: django, django-templates, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

i am using django-ckeditor as a `app_contect` field in models so How to apply multiple filters on a Django template , when i add multiple filters in html page it show error in my design

my code in html page :

```
<p class="card-text" id="font_control_for_all_pages">{{ android.app_contect|truncatechars:153|safe }}</p>
```

this photo without ( |safe )
[image]

and this with (|safe)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your issue relates to multiple filters or `ckeditor` as much as the fact that you're truncating HTML content and then trying to render it assuming the syntax is still valid/intact. You might want to look into [`truncatechars_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html) which will respect the underlying tags when performing the truncation instead of `truncatechars`